# How to present the STPPaymentOptionsViewController in swift ui

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, swiftui

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
    STPPaymentOptionsViewController()
}
```

I run this code hoping to present the Stripe Payment Options View Controller in my content view and I get this error:

Instance method `sheet(isPresented:onDismiss:content:)` requires that `STPAddCardViewController` conform to `View`

I also tried to wrap the view into a `UIViewRepresentable` like so:

```
struct PaymentOptionsView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> STPPaymentOptionsViewController {
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
        config.additionalPaymentOptions = .default
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
        config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "dummy-merchant-id"
        return STPPaymentOptionsViewController(configuration: config, e: STPTheme(), customerContext: STPCustomerContext(), delegate: self as! STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate)   
    }
}
```

Then I get the error:

Type `CheckOut.PaymentOptionsView` does not conform to protocol `UIViewRepresentable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that `STPPaymentOptionsViewController` inherits from `ViewController` you need to use `UIViewControllerRepresentable` instead.

You also need to implement the required delegate methods for the `STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate`.

```
struct PaymentOptionsView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate {
        var control: PaymentOptionsView

        init(_ control: PaymentOptionsView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        // Implement required delegate methods here:
        func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidCancel(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {

        }

        func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidFinish(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {

        }

        func paymentOptionsViewController(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {

        }
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) -> STPPaymentOptionsViewController {
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration()
        config.additionalPaymentOptions = .default
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
        config.appleMerchantIdentifier = "dummy-merchant-id"

        return STPPaymentOptionsViewController(configuration: config, theme: STPTheme(), apiAdapter: STPCustomerContext(), delegate: context.coordinator)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PaymentOptionsView>) { }
}
```

Keep in mind you're also setting the delegate in the `STPPaymentOptionsViewController` incorrectly. You need to use `context.coordinator` rather than `self as! STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate`.

Comment: After I did that the error: Type 'CheckOut.PaymentOptionsView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable' still came up and it asked me if I want to add protocol stubs, so I did that then it added in this line of code: typealias UIViewControllerType = type but I don't know what to put as the type of the view controller

Comment: That's because you need to implement the required delegate methods. See my answer for an example.